# Delete multiple row with radgrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am using Radgrid view with multi select row

I want to delete all selected records using checkbox in RadGrid

Code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
    AllowMultiRowSelection="true">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.aspx.vb

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
         For Each item As GridDataItem In RadGrid1.SelectedItems

            If item.Selected Then

            'Access data key

             Dim strID As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString()

            End If

         NEXT

       End Sub
```

The problem is when I use this method to get selected rows IDs to delete records, it is retrieving only one record ID and deleting the record for which the ID is retrieved.

Example: I am selecting records 1,2,3,4 and clicking the delete button, it is deleting only the record with ID=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know vs Basic very well. But I can say that,
you are loose your current ID knowledge in this command

```
Dim strID As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString()
```

every iteration in foreach, your strId variable update with new item id.

Maybe you can use concat string methods (maybe

```
strId += item.id
```

to save your all selected ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strID = string.Empty;

    foreach( GridDataItem grditem in  RadGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
        if (grditem.Selected)
        {
            strID = strID +  "," + grditem.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
        }
    }

    if (strID != string.Empty)
    {
        //your delete logic for db
        // pass strID it will contain 1,2,3,4
    }
}
```